# Contact form example not working with reCAPTCHA

Tags: css, recaptcha, contact-form

Would anyone be able to help me with this email contact form?
I have absolutely no idea what i'm doing with this and i've never done anything like it before.

I'm working with this example https://css-tricks.com/examples/NiceSimpleContactForm2/

I have put the example up at http://www.techagesite.com/contact/index.php

I'm not sure what i have to do to get the reCAPTCHA to work. In fact it doesn't even show up on the authors version online.

I dont know if im supposed to post the code for all of the included php files or if you can work it out from the example zip itself.

Comment: If theres an easier solution then using this one im happy to give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out this page, which is where this is shamelessly taken from:](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php)

From your code examples, it appears that you are trying to generate a recaptcaha in an `<iframe>`. This won't work very easily - the point of captcha is for you to submit a form with an additional value that your code is supposed to validate server side.

Just draft a normal HTML form (get rid of the iframe section), and then drop your php code that creates the recaptacha part, like this within the form (contact_form.php):

```
  <form method="post" action="verify.php">
    <?php
      require_once('recaptchalib.php');
      $publickey = "your_public_key"; // you got this from the signup page
      echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
    ?>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```

The php is replaced with javascript when the page is rendered. When a user submits your form, it gets posted to the url in `action` above, which is server side code that verifies the capatcha input (verify.php):

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "your_private_key";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
  ?>
```

That's it.